# More unlinked exchanges when switching background database from ecoinvent cut-off to consequential

Tags: brightway

I have an LCI inventory in excel that is originally linked to the ecoinvent 3.4 cut-off database. When I import it, I get no unlinked exchanges.

Now, I would like to switch and link it to the ecoinvent 3.4 consequential database.

```
for k, fp in {"LCI": "lci.xlsx"}.items():

    if k not in databases:
        imp = ExcelImporter(fp)
        imp.apply_strategies()
        imp.match_database(fields=["name", "unit", "location"]) 
        imp.match_database('ecoinvent_conseq',  fields=["reference product", "name", "unit", "location"])
        imp.match_database('ecoinvent_conseq',  fields=["name", "unit", "location"])
        imp.statistics()
        imp.write_excel()
        imp.write_database()
        database = Database('LCI')
```

For multi-output processes where there is a change in the reference product, I know why it does not get linked.

In some cases, the matching is not working even though the name, the location and the unit of the dataset are provided.

The matching works with these fields when I use the cut-off db but it does not with the consequential db.

What would be the reasons why these exchanges remain unlinked when switching to a consequential db?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional "unexplained" unlinked exchanges were resulting from the unmatched exchanges that were caused by the difference between the attributional and the consequential database (i.e. one unmatched exchanges trickled down to other unmatching).

The main difference is processes in the inventory where the reference product is different between both databases.

A typical example is a CHP process, with heat as determining product, used in the inventory to provide the reference product: "medium voltage, electricity". In CLCA, this cannot happen, so the strategy is simply to look for an alternative provider in the consequential database able to provide "medium voltage, electricity" as its own reference product.

Once these cases are resolved, the matching works perfectly with `fields=["name", "unit", "location"]`

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but when I installed the consequential version of ecoinvent 3.4 two flows were erased in the process. they are stored in the log. *venting of nitrogen, liquid* and *residual wood, dry*

Comment: yes, I saw your previous question. In this case, most of the processes that remain unlinked exist in both databases and have the same "name", "unit" and "location". But when I import LCI from excel the linking does not occur when I use a consequential db.